# How to bind property class objects to dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to bind the dataset with property class values. look at my peice of code.

```
public class BO_InputforgettingGrid
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string season { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

public DataSet Assortment_Criteria()
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//want to bind the above property class to this dataset.
}
```

At last my dataset should contain Brand,Market,season,Year as a Row values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your class (business object) directly. If you specify what kind of data binding you wanna achieve I can provide you code samples.
The other way is to convert your object to a type of DataTable (ADO.NET) and add this datatable to the DataSet object which is mainly used as a container for datatable objects.

```
public class BO_InputforgettingGridWrapper
{
    private BO_InputforgettingGrid baseobject;

    public BO_InputforgettingGridWrapper(BO_InputforgettingGrid obj)
    {
         baseobject = obj;
    }
    public string RowText 
    { 
       get
       {
           return string.Format("{0}{1}...", baseobject.Brand ...);
       }
    }
}
```

So you can use the code below to convert your object to a single column datatable.
Look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/904608.aspx?Converting+an+Object+to+dataTable+in+C+) for a convertation of objects to datatable for instance.

Comment: just want to bind the all business object names to the datatable or dataset in single column..